# How to enable vim addon packages?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, vim, package-management

I have installed `vim-nox` as well as `vim-latexsuite` and `vim-outliner` on Ubuntu 12.10. There's nothing wrong with Vim but neither of the add-on packages does anything. What do I have to do to in order to enable them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Vim add-ons are not enabled for all users by default. To use an add-on, use [`vim-addons`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/vim-addon-manager):

```
$ vim-addon-manager 
# Name                     User Status  System Status 
editexisting                removed       removed       
justify                     removed       removed       
latex-suite                 removed       removed       
matchit                     removed       removed       
vimoutliner                 removed       removed

$ vim-addons install latex-suite
$ vim-addons install vimoutliner
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tested various plugin managers for vim, and find pathogen the best of them all. I first tried vundle which was recommended on this site (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458398/packageplugin-management-for-vim), but found it too complex.

What I wanted was a way to keep each plugin in it's own directory. Pathogen does just that: every plugin in ~/.vim/bundle is activated automatically.

pathogen is really very simple:

- you install the pathogen plugin
- add `call pathogen#infect()` to .vimrc
- when you want to try a package, you install it into a directory in .vim/bundle/... Pathogen will activate it automatically.
- to get rid of a package, you just remove it from .vim/bundle. I have a directory .vim/bundle.off where I move unused packages which I might use sometime later.